# UiScrollView scrolling UiView

Tags: animation, uiview, scrollview

in my viewcontroller entered all the objects in a scrollview. One of the buttons inside the scrollView creates an animation.

The scrollView get off the page -80.0 orgine.y
So far so good .. Now I want that when you click on the button the scrollview and then goes back down to -80.0 to +80.0 automatically returning to its original position so ... Can you tell me the best method for you to have this?

This is the action that fulfills my button when pushed ...

```
- (IBAction)AcceptFriendRequest:(id)sender {

    PFObject *SelectedUser = [self.UtentiInAttesa objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
    [SelectedUser setObject:@"Confermato" forKey:@"STATO"];

    [SelectedUser saveInBackground];



     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
     [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
     FFScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(FFScrollView.frame.origin.x, (FFScrollView.frame.origin.y - 80.0), FFScrollView.frame.size.width, FFScrollView.frame.size.height);
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

     [UIView commitAnimations];



}
```

Comment: This might be very good start for your to handle this question: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/ViewPG_iPhoneOS.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button event handler

```
- (IBAction)myBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    // Create new CGRect indicate place where you would scroll to.
    // Assume it is called `originalRect`
    // Use the following method, it should work
    [FFScrollView.scroll scrollRectToVisible:originalRect animated:YES];
}
```